# I need to create a new SQL table based on a table that will refresh every 3 hours

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, calculation

I have a table with the name RTM_SO which gets it data via an ETL pipeline which has the following steps:

1. It truncates the table.
2. It uploads the new data into the table.

Now I want to create a side table RTM_SO_Totals with calculations based on the initial ETL pipeline. So once the RTM_SO table gets updated I want to trigger the calculations and create a table as example:

| Refresh Date/Time | Date and Time of the refresh ex: 01-03-2023 11:15 |
| --- | --- |
| #SO's | Total amount of SOs calculation |
| #Pallets | Total amount of pallets calculation |

The calculations itself will not be the issue, I am struggling with getting the actions aligned and running the calculations based on the trigger to the new report.

So I need to know how I can setup the SQL table to refresh based on the trigger and then create the new table which also includes the Date/Time stamp etc.

I tried to adjust the ETL pipeline to write the totals to the new table.
The calculations and getting the date/time stamp were not working.

Comment: Your "table" doesn't appear to be a table, it seems like a report. The columns are not representing the same thing on each row. If you can show your `CREATE TABLE` statement, plus the ETL calculation code, that would be great.

Comment: Can't your ETL call some procedure when it finished with RTM_SO? So you can do what you need.